# Is there a way to share app link with users to download app using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to share app link with users to download app using flutter? Or to share app with users to download the app in flutter

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, flutter compiles to native apps, so you can upload them to your platforms appstore.

Comment: Actually my app is like a playstore like it is an app generator 
A user should be able to share the app with other users so that they can download it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so my solution solved your problem?